# NullPointerException for ArrayList when calling "add"?

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, nullpointerexception

whenever i run the following code it gives me `NullPointerException.`although i checking if not null then add, but still giving that eception.the `file` is a plain text`(.txt)`
what could be wrong?

```
BufferedReader  br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
ArrayList<String> keArrayList=null;
for(int i=0;br2.readLine()!=null;i++)
{
  String  letter= br2.readLine();
  if (letter!=null)
    keArrayList.add(i,letter);
}
```

Comment: ArrayList<String> keArrayList = null <- your ArrayList is null. You have to make an instance of it before you can add stuff to it in the for loop.

Comment: In addition to the answers you have gotten, does your reading loop do what you want? First you read a line, and if that is not null, then you read another line and store in your list. So, you will only be storing every other line. This might be your intention but I wanted to point out the behavior to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`keArrayList` is `null`:

```
ArrayList<String> keArrayList=null;
```

Change to:

```
List<String> keArrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 2):

you have set keArrayList to be null just prior to your loop.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you hadn't created any **instance** of ArrayList to use at first place. `ArrayList<String> keArrayList` is only a field (placeholder) for a real `ArrayList<String>` object. Therefore you need to simply change that line to:

```
ArrayList<String> keArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now you are creating a real `ArrayList` object and storing it in that field.

**You can read more here:**

- [Java Tutorials - Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)
- [Java Tutorials - What is an Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html)
- [Java Tutorials - Creating Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

Answer (score 2):

you have just declared the object you have to instantiate and initialize it as well.

**Declaration:** The code set in bold are all variable declarations that associate a variable name with an object type.

**Instantiation:** The new keyword is a Java operator that creates the object.

**Initialization:** The new operator is followed by a call to a constructor, which initializes the new object.

please read about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the stacktrace to know where exactly the NullPointerException is occuring. You are checking null for 'letter', but are you checking for keArrayList ??NO, that's why you are getting the Exception at `keArrayList.add(i,letter);`